# When does Oracle still treat empty strings as NULL?

Tags: oracle, null, varchar, string

I was looking for the difference between `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` and learned, among other things, that Oracle’s `VARCHAR2` treats empty strings as `NULL`, or the other way round. Also, apparently I should be using `VARCHAR2`, and that `VARCHAR` is reserved for the future.

In my blissful ignorance, I have a table where I created a column using `VARCHAR`, and I certainly don’t get the same:

```sql
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE state='';
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE IS NULL;      --  not the same
```

I’m using Version 18.0.0.0.0, so it wouldn’t surprise me to find that the future they were talking about has finally arrived. All the answers I have found mentioning this are pretty old.

Here is a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/yeWEbcDF

I tested in 11g, 18c and 21c.

Comment: 21c appears to treat VARCHAR and varchar2 the same way: https://dbfiddle.uk/MFFuOXvP

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini which is to say that `IS NULL` is not treated the same as `=''`.

Comment: Of course, the way Oracle treats '' will make ''='' a contradiction, but there is no difference between VARCHAR and varchar2 in that regard

Comment: Can't help wondering why they did not implement this brilliant idea for 0 as well;-)

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini Actually, I think this is a risky idea. A price of `0` (free) is different to a price of `NULL` (unpriced?).

Comment: It was a joke, '' is the identity element for concatenation of strings the same way as 0 is the identity element for addition of numbers

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini Sorry, I missed the Irony ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because `NULL is NULL` is true, but `NULL = NULL` isn't.

```
SQL> select * from dual where null = null;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from dual where null is null;

D
-
X

SQL> select * from dual where '' is null;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

[Nulls with Comparison Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-29B6554B-C948-4A8E-81C1-696A5128AAAD)

> To test for nulls, use only the comparison conditions IS NULL and IS
> NOT NULL. If you use any other condition with nulls and the result
> depends on the value of the null, then the result is UNKNOWN. **Because
> null represents a lack of data, a null cannot be equal or unequal to
> any value or to another null.**

Comment: "`NULL = NULL` is false" no it's `UNKNOWN`. For example you cannot do `NOT (NULL = NULL)` because that is *also* `UNKNOWN`

Comment: @Charlieface, UNKNOWN is only one possible interpretion of NULL.  NOT_APPLICABLE is another one. So I would say that NULL = NULL is NULL

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini Possibly, but I think the standard defines it as `UNKNOWN`. Comes to the same logical result. Either way, definitely not `FALSE`.

Comment: Agreed, and you may be right about UNKNOWN (cant look it up at the moment). Personally I would prefer MISSING or NULL over UNKNOWN since the latter indicates that there is a value, we just don't know it. In practice NULL is used in other ways as well. It is also interesting to see how we get into trouble when we try to reason about it in a natural language (not having a different meaning there).

Comment: @Charlieface, I cant find any thing more recent than the 2011 draft (http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip). It is a bit vauge on the subject. In Framework - Definitions 3.1.1.12 it says: "null value: special value that is used to indicate the absence of any data value". In 4.4.2: "Although the null value is neither equal to any other value nor not equal to any other value — it is unknown
whether or not it is equal to any given value..." 4.4.3.4: "A value of the Boolean data type is either true or false. The truth value of unknown is sometimes represented
by the null value.".